# How to compose Query String from dropdown menus

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

Lets asume we have 2 dropdown menus. I would like to be able to select an item from those dropdowns and pass the selected item's value as a parameter (or placeholder) to a query string. 
Something like:

```
SELECT {1} FROM {2}
```

Currently I am using sqldatasource but I cannot find a way to control the query from the dropdown menus.
Furthermore the first dropdown should have an item like "Select everything" and the value passed to the query string must be " * "
I am sure that this is a very common proccess but I cant find a straight forward example or a tutorial that I can easily understand. So any advice or example would help a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is advanced query builder. It is not a common process. I spent a lot of time to build on and still it is not perfect. Moreover you must be careful with building query because if just fill what you receive from query string, somebody can drop your database.

There are some commercial query builder like EasyQuery. Checkout [demo](http://demo.easyquerybuilder.com/asp-net-ajax/) and [prices](http://devtools.korzh.com/easyquery/purchase/)

Comment: I dont understand exactly what advanced query builder is. You can't pass the value of a selected dropdown item to a string without using commercial software?

Comment: Of course you can: just add DropDownList and this control will pass value on submit